# pytest functions don't return data to be used in following functions in the same pytest file?

Tags: python, pytest

I have developed a program (file.py) formed by a few functions and now I want to test each of these functions from test_file.py. I have tested the first function correctly but when I have wanted to test the second function I have noticed that I need the data generated from the first function. What is the best way to do this?

My first attend has been this

```
def test_load_sample():  # The first test for the first function
    '''Verify all rows of the body of the vcf file are taken'''
    data_to_test = load_sample (NAME_FILE_1) # load_sample() is the first function of file.py
    return data_to_test     # I need this data for the following tests
    assert len(data_to_test) == 1400
    

data_to_test = data_to_test
```

Because I expected that the function test_load_sample would return the data I want for the second test. However, it seems that pytest function doesn't return what has been tested?

What is the best way to do this? Am I doing something wrong? This is my first time working with pytest.

EDIT

```
# File.py

input_data = 1

function_1(data):
return data +1

data1 = function_1(input_data)

# Now input data is 2

function_2(data):
return data +1

data2 = function_2(data1)
...
```

Now I want to test the function to test function_2

```
test_function_1():
data_to_test = function_1(data_input)
assert data_to_test = 2

test_function_2():
# I need data_to_test from the previous function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this

```
def test_load_sample():
    '''Verify all rows of the body of the vcf file are taken'''
    data_to_test = load_sample (NAME_FILE_1)
    return data_to_test
    assert len(data_to_test) == 1400
    

data_to_test = test_load_sample()
# Now, data_to_test can be used in the following test functions
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not the convention (probably anti-pattern). Some points that you should consider:

- Test functions are not meant to return any value. They are just used to run the source code and perform assertions on the results, nothing more.
- Each test should be designed to be isolated from each other, in a way that if test1 fails, that doesn't mean test2 to test10 will also fail.
- Also, such isolation is needed because depending on the way tests are run, they may be executed in parallel (at the same time) and not sequentially. Thus making test2 to depend on test1 would fail if there are times that test2 was executed first.

If you have a common resource that you want to share across multiple testcases, configure it in the tests. So if the output of `load_sample(NAME_FILE_1)` will be used in multiple tests and you don't want it to be re-executed anew for every test case, you may want to use a pytest fixture with [session scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes).

> session: the fixture is destroyed at the end of the test session.

So for this test:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def my_funcion_fixture():
    print("Function fixture initialized")
    return 123


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def my_session_fixture():
    print("Session fixture initialized")
    return 456
    # Ideally, this is where you put <data_to_test = load_sample (NAME_FILE_1)> and return the <data_to_test>


def test_first(my_funcion_fixture, my_session_fixture):
    assert my_funcion_fixture == 123
    assert my_session_fixture == 456


def test_second(my_funcion_fixture, my_session_fixture):
    assert my_funcion_fixture == 123
    assert my_session_fixture == 456


def test_third(my_funcion_fixture, my_session_fixture):
    assert my_funcion_fixture == 123
    assert my_session_fixture == 456


def test_fourth(my_funcion_fixture, my_session_fixture):
    assert my_funcion_fixture == 123
    assert my_session_fixture == 456
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
....
[100%]
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_first ________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session fixture initialized
Function fixture initialized
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_second _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function fixture initialized
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_third ________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function fixture initialized
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_fourth _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function fixture initialized
4 passed in 0.07s
```

- As you can see, we are able to use all fixtures in all our tests. The only difference is that our session fixture `my_session_fixture` was only instantiated once and not re-executed for every test case.